# value searching in an ascending arrays in two different ways

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am doing a project for my C class. We are going to find the value in an ascending array with 10 distinctive numbers, then search the value users wanna and return the index of the searching number. The first method is called Linear Search which compare each element in the array to the value user wanted. The second method is called Binary, which you take the middle index compare with the searching value. If List[middle] = target element then return the variable middle which is the index of the element. In the case that target element is greater than List[Middle], then continue the process on the right half of the array. If it is lesser, then continue the same process on the left half of the array. The process of halving is done only until the ‘Left’ index variable is less than or equal to the ‘Right’ index variable. In case the target element is not found , -1 is returned.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int array[10];
    int i = 0,value;
    printf("Please enter 10 distinctive postive numbers with ascending             order.");
    for(i;i<10;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
    printf("What value are you seaching for?");
    scanf("%d",value);
    printf("searchLinear(value,*array[10],10)");

    return 0;   
}

int searchLinear(int s,int *list[10],int n){
    list[n];
    int i = 0;
    for(i;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(s == *list[i])
            return *list[i];
    }
    if(i = n)
        return -1;
}   
int searchBinary(int s, int *list[10],int n) {
    list[n];
    int i,left,right,middle;
    left = 0;
    right = n-1;

    for(i = 0;i<n/2;i++)
    {
        middle = (left + right)/2;

        if(*list[middle] > s)   
            right = middle;
        else if(*list[middle] < s)
            left = middle;
        else if(*list[middle] = s)
            return *list[middle];

        if(left == right)
            return -1;  
    }
}
```

This is my code, looks like it runs into an infinite loop. How can I fix it?

Comment: `if(i = n)` -->> `if(i == n)`

Comment: It true! Thanks! I am still trying to figure out how to run it.

Comment: Turn on warnings, usually that means to compile with the `-Wall` flag, and fix all of them. They will explain why your code isn't working (or at least the first set of basic problems).

Comment: and one more: `else if(*list[middle] = s)` -->> `else if(*list[middle] == s)` (possibly harmles) BTW: the `int searchBinary()` function sometimes returns a random value.

Comment: What do you mean by -wall flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corrected code is

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    int searchLinear(int s,int list[],int n);
    int searchBinary(int s, int list[],int n);   //you need to give forward declaration of funcs

int main()
    {
        int array[10];
        int i = 0,value;
        printf("Please enter 10 distinctive postive numbers with ascending       order.");
        for(i;i<10;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&array[i]);
        }
        printf("What value are you seaching for?");
        scanf("%d",&value);        //you missed & here
        printf("%d",searchBinary(value,array,10));

        return 0;   
    }

    int searchLinear(int s,int list[],int n){      // you can use this format of arguments
        //list[n];        //what did you wanted to do with this line
        int i = 0;
        for(i;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(s == list[i])
                return i;             //return index not value
        }
        if(i = n)
            return -1;
    }   
     int searchBinary(int s, int list[],int n){
        //list[n];
        int i,left,right,middle;
        left = 0;
        right = n-1;

        for(i = 0;i<n/2;i++)
        {
            middle = (left + right)/2;
             if(left > right)      //you have to check left>right, instead of left==right
                return -1;  
            if(list[middle] > s)   
                right = middle-1;
            else if(list[middle] < s)
                left = middle+1;
            else if(list[middle] == s)    //== is used for comparision
                return middle;

        }
    }
```

**Observe the corrections in comments**

Comment: What a excellent explanation. I forgot declaring the function. I do not know why I did not declare before and it was running perfectly.    I also tried to run the program with a start before the list[],(int *list[]) in the two function. But I cannot figure it out. It generates the errors below : search.c:17:3: warning: passing argument 2 of 'searchLinear' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
search.c:2:5: note: expected 'int **' but argument is of type 'int'

Comment: it is because int list is itself a pointer, adding a star before it makes it a pointer of pointer, and when u pass list[] to it, it gives the conversion error

Comment: If the answer was helpful, you can upvote and mark it as correct , which makes it more beneficial for others users

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation is awesome! I marked urs as correct answer!!